# Code for adding text to every HTML file on website

Tags: javascript, php, html, web

So I have a website, https://coolkids.gq. I want to be able to add a certain line of code to every single HTML file on the website using another HTML, JavaScript or PHP file, but I am not sure how to do this.

How would I be able to write a script to add a line of custom code to every HTML page on my website?

Edit: As pointed out by charlieftl, I should clarify that all files are saved in either the /htdocs folder or in a folder inside of that.

Comment: Question is far too broad without knowing more about your site architecture and how these pages are served

Comment: Good point, charlieftl. All files are saved in either the /htdocs folder or in a folder inside of that so it might be possible to do a search of the directory.

Comment: Still not enough detail for a solid solution. Might be able to do a find/replace using text editor though

Answer (score 0):

yes you can, just make some folder named include or whatever and create for example loginForm.html sth like

```
<div>
<form>
....
</form>
</div>
```

and in pages where you want to put it use
`<?php require('./include/loginForm.html') ?>;` in place where you need it

Of course it need to be PHP page.

Good thing is to have also included header and footer in external html and include it on every php page ;D

if you want some js script in every page you need to add it manualy:
`<script src="js/main.js"></script>`
but it can be included in footer.